# facebook like button not showing correct information - tried debugging

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

We are using a facebook like button on a gallery page. When you click the like button, the parent page information is provided instead of the "item" information - but when the link is shared individually on facebook, it pulls the right information.

I tried using Facebook's debug tool, and it pulls the correct information.. the issue seems to be when its on the page. I've checked the meta info and it all looks right...

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a specific link it´s pretty hard to find out what´s wrong...

Comment: Are you sure you're not pointing the like button at a different URL?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Put in the correct sub-link and generate the like button again > **Test it first, directly in the like button generator**.

If the data is shown correctly in the debugger, then i am pretty sure the problem is that you don´t use the correct/same link in the like button. It would be important to see your usage of the like button. It´s possible that you have an escape character problem, so only the basic link is used.